# I have an Uncharted 3 redeem code for PS3 but it's expired. Can I get another?

Tags: ps3

I have an Uncharted 3 redeem code for PS3 but it's expired. Can I somehow get a working code from it?

Comment: Are you saying the code is expired?

Answer (score 0):

If your redeem code has expired, there is no way you can get a new one, unless wherever you got it is feeling generous enough and you are able to contact them.